# Proof Verification: $|\bigcup \mathscr{A}| \leq | \mathscr{A}| \cdot \kappa$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

**Synopsis**

Please verify my proof. I would also appreciate any tips on how I might improve my mathematical writing. Thank you.

*If my proof is without major issues, please note that I might delete the question soon afterwards.*

**Exercise**

> If every member of a set $\mathscr{A}$ has cardinality $\kappa$ or
> less, then $$\text{card } \bigcup \mathscr{A} \leq (\text{card }
> \mathscr{A}) \cdot \kappa$$

**Proof**

Let $K$ be a set of cardinality $\kappa$. Consider the function $F: \bigcup \mathscr{A} \rightarrow A \times K$ defined by $F(x) = (A_x, g_x(x))$ where $A_x$ is the corresponding set in $\mathscr{A}$ such that $x \in A_x \subseteq \bigcup \mathscr{A}$ and $g_x$ is an injection from $A_x$ into $K$ guaranteed by our initial conditions. Then $F$ describes a suitable injection from $\bigcup \mathscr{A}$ into $\mathscr{A} \times K$ and $\text{card} \bigcup \mathscr{A} \leq (\text{card } \mathscr{A}) \cdot \kappa$.

*Note: I was wondering if the "choosing" of an injection $g_x$ requires me to state that I am utilizing the Axiom of Choice*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function $F$ is not well-defined: what if $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ for $A\neq B \in \mathscr{A}$? You might be able to solve this by assuming the sets in $\mathscr{A}$ are disjoint and then use something like
$$\left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right| \le \left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \times \{i\}\right|$$

Via cardinal arithmetic, an easy proof is the following:

$$\left|\bigcup \mathscr{A} \right| \le \sum_{A \in \mathscr{A}}|A| \leq \sum_{A \in \mathscr{A}} \kappa = |\mathscr{A}| \kappa $$

Comment: I haven't yet learned cardinal arithmetic, but I was wondering what $\left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right| \le \left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \times \{i\}\right|$ would do to fix my proof? Also, is it possible to just choose one of the sets $A$ or $B$ by utilizing AoC? Must it be well defined? I'm still new to this so please forgive me if any of these are dumb questions.

Comment: @mijucik: Yes, it must. What is Enderton’s definition of $|\mathscr{A}|$?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott I see. I'm not sure what you mean by "Enderton's definition of $|\mathscr{A}|$" though.

Comment: @mijucik: The question uses the notation $\operatorname{card}\mathscr{A}$; what definition of that are you using?

Comment: Oh. He hasn't yet defined cardinal numbers; only equinumerosity. So all proofs still rely on just finding bijections and injections between them. In other words, I know how to prove equal cardinality, or if one set has larger cardinality than the other, but I'm not sure what cardinality actually is per se.

Comment: Cardinal arithmetic is defined using sets representing those cardinalities and not the cardinalities themselves if that makes sense.

Comment: @mijucik: In that case, how is the product $(\operatorname{card}\mathscr{A})\cdot\kappa$ defined? Or does $\operatorname{card}A\le(\operatorname{card}B)\cdot(\operatorname{card}C)$ just mean that there is an injection from $A$ into $B\times C$?

Comment: Essentially. I don't know what $\text{card} \mathscr{A} \cdot \kappa$ means strictly, so I must use representative sets and injections to prove exercises. He leaves the definition of cardinal numbers as a "promise" for the next chapter, which is on ordinals.

Comment: @mijucik: That makes it more difficult than necessary to give a rigorous argument. The simplest that I can see right now is to use AC to assign to each $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ an $A_x\in\mathscr{A}$ and to use it again to assign to each $A\in\mathscr{A}$ an injection $g_A:A\to K$. Then you can set $F(x)=\langle A_x,g_{A_x}(x)\rangle$, and your argument will work.

Comment: I see. That's what I was thinking too. Do you have any idea what the original poster was hinting at with $\left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i\right| \le \left|\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \times \{i\}\right|$ by the way? I'm confused what it even means.

Comment: @mijucik: The idea is to convert an arbitrary family of sets into a pairwise disjoint family. I’ll do it without introducing an extraneous $I$. For each $A\in\mathscr{A}$ let $A'=A\times\{A\}$, and let $\mathscr{A}'=\{A':A\in\mathscr{A}\}$. Then $\mathscr{A}'$ is a pairwise disjoint family, and for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$ the map $\varphi_A:A\to A':a\mapsto\langle a,\{A\}\rangle$ is a bijection. For each $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{A}'$ there is a unique $A_x'\in\mathscr{A}'$ such that $x\in A_x'$, so something like your $F$ would be well-defined, but you’d still have the problem of showing that ...

Comment: ... there’s an injection of $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ into $\bigcup\mathscr{A}'$, and right now I don’t see a way to do that that isn’t essentially equivalent to using AC to pick out an $A_x$ for each $x$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help again. What a confusing problem.

Comment: @mijucik: You’re welcome.